# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar solo un checkbox de dos y evitar que el seleccionado se desmarque al dar click en la misma?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, input

Me gustaría saber la solución con javascript (si es posible) en marcar solo un checkbox de dos o mas y evitar  que al dar clic en el seleccionado se desmarque. ¿Me podrían ayudar?.

Comment: Para que puedas recibir ayuda es necesario publiques un [mcve] donde expongas que has intentado, lee [ask]

Comment: Hola, si solo son dos opciones podrías considerar usar mejor 
Radio Buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar una función que se ejecute cada vez que hay un cambio en alguno de los checkbox. Cuando se encuentre seleccionado el checkbox y se quiera deseleccionar entrara en la condición if y volverá a seleccionar el checkbox mediante la propiedad checked.

```js
function verifica_seleccion(check){
    if(!check.checked){
        check.checked=1;
    }
}
```

Cada elemento checkbox tiene asignada la funcion verifica_seleccion(this) en su propiedad onchange para asegurarse que una vez seleccionado, así se mantenga.

```html
<form name="f1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check1" onchange="verifica_seleccion(this)" value="Check1">Check1
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check2" onchange="verifica_seleccion(this)" value="Check2" >Check2
    <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="check3" onchange="verifica_seleccion(this)" value="Check3" >Check3
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias era justo lo que necesitaba. Gracias por tu colaboración valiosa.